# Exercise 11, Section 5.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $K$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $D$ be an alternating $2$-linear function on $2 \times 2$ matrices over $K$, Show that $D(A) = (\text{det} A)D(I)$ for all $A$. Now use this result (no computations with the entries allowed) to show that $\text{det} (AB) = (\text{det} A)(\text{det} B)$ for any $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ over $K$.

**My attempt:** Since $D$ is $2$-linear, we have $D(A)$ $=A_{11}A_{21}D(e_1,e_1)$ $+$ $A_{11}A_{22}D(e_1,e_2)$ $+$ $A_{12}A_{21}D(e_2,e_1)$ $+$ $A_{12}A_{22}D(e_2,e_2)$, by example 2 section 5.2. Since $D$ is alternating, we have $D(e_1,e_1)$ $=D(e_2,e_2)$ $=0$ and $D(e_2,e_1)$ $=-D(e_1,e_2)$. So $D(A)$ $=A_{11}A_{22}D(e_1,e_2)$ $-$ $A_{12}A_{21}D(e_1,e_2)$ $=A_{11}A_{22}D(I)$ $-$ $A_{12}A_{21}D(I)$ $=\text{det}(A)\cdot D(I)$. **Is my proof correct?**

Unfortunately I can’t prove $\text{det}(A\cdot B)=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(B)$ without computing entries of $A$, $B$.

Comment: That key that says "Enter" in your keyboard can be used to begin a new line, and make your prose actually readable.

Comment: You can use the first result on $R(A)=D(AB)$.

Comment: @user85667 what is $R(A)$?

Comment: A new function that satisfies the conditions of the problem (check it), which value at $A$ is $D(AB)$. Ah, and start with a $D$ such that $D(I)=1$.

Comment: @user85667 Can you please give more hints?

Comment: Define your $D$ such that $D(I)=1$. Define $R(A)=D(AB)$. Since this satisfies the condition of the first part, then $R(A)=(\det(A))R(I)=(\det(A))D(B)=(\deta(A))(\det(B))D(I)$. On the other hand $D(AB)=(\det(AB))D(I)$. Then $\det(AB)=R(AB)=(\det(A))(\det(B))$.

Comment: @user85667 ohhh…. Now I see bigger picture ([see](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4542368/861687)). Still I think your hint is vague. Instead of saying “ You can use the first result on $R(A)=D(AB)$, you could have said: Fix $B\in M_2(K)$. Define $R:M_2(K)\to K$ such that $R(A)=\text{det}(AB)$ satisfy following properties, $R$ is alternative and $2$-linear. By result of first part, $R(A)=\text{det}(A)R(I)$. Thus $R(A)$ $=\text{det}(AB)$ $= \text{det}(A)R(I)$ $= \text{det}(A) \text{det}(B)$. No need to define determinant function $D$. Because by uniqueness $D=\text{det}$.