# Exercise 9, Section 5.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $K$ be a commutative ring with identity and $D$ an alternating $n$-linear function on $n\times n$ matrices over $K$. Show that
>
> (a) $D(A) = 0$, if one of the rows of $A$ is $0$.
>
> (b) $D(B) = D(A)$, if $B$ is obtained from $A$ by adding a scalar multiple of one row of $A$ to another.

**My attempt:** **(a)** Let $A=(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_i,..,\alpha_n)\in M_n(K)$ such that $\alpha_i=0=[0\dotsb 0]$. Let $\alpha’_i=\alpha_j$, for some $i\neq j$. Since $D$ is $n$-linear, we have $D(c\alpha_i+\alpha’_i)$ $=cD(\alpha_i)+D(\alpha’_i)$ $=D(\alpha_j)$ $=cD(\alpha_i)+D(\alpha_j)$. Since $D$ is alternating, we have $D(\alpha_j)$ $=D(\alpha_1,.,\alpha_j,.,\alpha_j,.,\alpha_n)$ $=0$. So $cD(\alpha_i)=0$. Take $c=1_K$. Hence $D(\alpha_i)=D(A)=0$.

**(b)** Let $A=(\alpha_1,.,\alpha_i,.,\alpha_j,.,\alpha_n)$ and $B=(\alpha_1,.,\alpha_i+c\alpha_j,.,\alpha_j,.,\alpha_n)$; $i\neq j$. Since $D$ is $n$-linear, we have $D(B)$ $=D(\alpha_i+c\alpha_j)$ $=D(\alpha_i)+cD(\alpha_j)$ $=D(A)+cD(\alpha_j)$. Since $D$ is alternating, we have $D(\alpha_j)$ $=D(\alpha_1,.,\alpha_j,.,\alpha_j,.,\alpha_n)$ $=0$. So $D(B)$ $=D(A)+c\cdot 0$ $=D(A)$. Hence $D(B)=D(A)$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Can you use the fact that an alternating multilinear function must be a constant times the determinant?

Comment: @P.Lawrence I know that fact, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4536234/861687) is the proof. But don’t see a way to use that fact in above problem.

Comment: @user264745 Yes, your proof is correct