# Theorem 3, Section 5.3 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, determinant

> Let $K$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices over $K$. Then $\text{det}(A\cdot B)=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(B)$.
>
> **Hoffman’s proof:** Let $B$ be a fixed $n\times n$ matrix over $K$. Define $D:M_{n}(K)\to K$ such that $D(A)=\text{det}(AB)$, $\forall A\in M_n(K)$. If we denote the rows of $A$ by $a_l,…,a_n$, then $$D(A)=D(\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n)=\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(\alpha_1B,…,\alpha_nB).$$ Here $\alpha_jB$ denotes the $1\times n$ matrix which is the product of the $1\times n$ matrix $\alpha_j$ and the $n\times n$ matrix $B$……

**Que:** How to rigorous show $AB=(\alpha_1B,…,\alpha_nB)$?

**My attempt:** Fix $i\in J_n$. Then $(AB)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}\cdot B_{kj}=\alpha_i\cdot C_j^B$, where $C_j^B$ is $j$th column of $B$. So $i$th row of $AB$ is $[\alpha_i\cdot C_1^B\dotsb \alpha_i\cdot C_n^B]$ $=\alpha_i\cdot B$. Since $i$ was arbitrary, $i$th row of $AB$ is $\alpha_i\cdot B$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Hence $AB=(\alpha_1B,…,\alpha_nB)$. **Is my proof correct?**

**Approach(2):** [This](https://youtu.be/LV1aApOYwVc) video shows different but little bit hard proof of $\text{det}(A\cdot B)=\text{det}(A)\cdot \text{det}(B)$.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but I don't understand Hoffman's proof. It shows that there is a function that takes $A$ into $\det (AB)$, but how does that imply that $\det (A) \det (B) = \det (AB)$?

Comment: @PauloSigiani We show map $D$ is alternative and $n$-linear. which implies $D(A)=\text{det}(A)D(I)$. It’s easy to check $D(I)=\text{det}(B)$. So $D(A)$ $= \text{det}(AB)$ $= \text{det}(A)\text{det}(B)$.